# Display input text on dropdown in angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm new to angular front-end development and I was wondering if there's a way in which I can dynamically create a dropdown list of values captured from an input field.

I created the below image via an image editor to give an idea of what I'm looking for.

[dropdownImageExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTE0X.png)

So when I type in the string 'Special' in the input field and I press the key enter on my keyboard, I'd like that string to appear in the dropdown list alongside 'None' and 'Clean'.

The below is what I have in my code so far.

html:

```
<div class="inputDiv">
   <label>Result Type</label>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="resultType" (keyup.enter)="enterResultType()"> 
 </div>
```

ts:

```
resultType= '';
resultTypeDropdownList = [{ item_id: 1, item_text: 'None' },
  { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Clean' }];

enterResultType(){
   this.resultTypeDropdownList.push({ item_id: this.resultTypeDropdownList.length+1, item_text: this.resultType});
 }
```

I'd like the values in my array to appear in the dropdown. Hope it makes sense

Comment: The HTML <datalist> element might be what you're looking for

Comment: I've never styled it before though so I don't know how hard that is to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zexkxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). If not found go to this link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zexkxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Lemme know if anything is required.

Thanks

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  listItems = [];

  form: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      item: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }
  addToListReq() {
    this.listItems.push(this.form.value.item);
  }
  delete(item) {
    this.listItems.splice(item, 1);
  }
}
```

### app.component.css

```css
.inner-wrap input,
.list {
  width: 16rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.inner-wrap .list {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.inner-wrap .list label {
  background-color: #4267b2;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.outer-wrap .inner-wrap .displayEmpty {
  height: 1.5rem;
}
span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
.inner-wrap {
  width: 655px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

### app.component.html

```html
<span for="">Result type</span>
<div class="outer-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type and click enter"
        text="#ref"
        formControlName="item"
        (keydown.enter)="addToListReq(text)"
      />
    </form>
    <div class="list" [ngClass]="listItems.length == 0 ? 'displayEmpty' : ''">
      <label
        for=""
        id="{{ i }}"
        *ngFor="let item of listItems; let i = index"
        (click)="delete(i)"
        >{{ item }} <i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i
      ></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)